# How to sort results by relevance in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I write a DQL to find some results and I want it returns the best top 10 results, how to sort the results by relevance in Doctrine ?

`$posts = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT p  FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Post p WHERE p.title LIKE :word')
    ->setParameter('word', '%' . $word . '%')
    ->setMaxResults(10)
    ->getResult();`

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is similar with my question:

[How to use Doctrine_RawSql for a fulltext search and sorting by relevance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385988/how-to-use-doctrine-rawsql-for-a-fulltext-search-and-sorting-by-relevance)

So, I see.

According to the MySQL fulltext natural language search docs:

> When MATCH() is used in a WHERE clause, as in the example shown earlier, the rows returned are automatically sorted with the highest relevance first. Relevance values are nonnegative floating-point numbers. Zero relevance means no similarity. Relevance is computed based on the number of words in the row, the number of unique words in that row, the total number of words in the collection, and the number of documents (rows) that contain a particular word.